# Panda is overwriting a datetime list into timestamp when inserting a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have a list of datetime values that I want to add to a column in a panda. However, whenever I add it as a column, the values get changed to type time stamp. How do I get it so that I can keep that column and its values as type datetime?

```
Code: 
#partialDates is a datetime list
#partialddf is a panda dataframe

print 'Type as an independent list:'
print type(partialDates[0]) 
partialddf['A'] = partialDates
print 'Type once inside panda as a colum:'
print type(partialddf['A'].tolist()[0])





Output:
Type as an independent list:
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
Type once inside panda as a colum:
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your list?

Comment: This is partial dates printed to console:   [datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 28, 0, 0)]